# Why doesn't my if-else statement work?

Tags: javascript, url, if-statement

Can anyone see why this does not work:

```
<script>
  if (url==showbasket.html||order1.html||order2.html||order3.html||order4.html) {
     document.write('<span style="font-family:lucida;font-size:10px;">Hello</span>');
  } else {
     document.write('<span style="font-family:lucida;font-size:30px;">Hello Hello</span>');
  }
</script>
```

I´m trying to write a script that do this:

```
IF URL = 1.html or 2.html or 3.html or 4.html THEN 
    write option1 
ELSE 
    write option2 (for all other URL´s)
```

Comment: `url`, `showbasket`, `order1`,... are all undefined variables. I assume `showbasket.html` etc should be strings, so you have to put quotation marks around them. What should `url` be?

Answer (score 3):

```
if (url == "showbasket.html" || url == "order1.html" || url == "order2.html" || url == "order3.html" || url == "order4.html")
```

You have to do the check for each url and if it's a string use quotes

Comment: So I can´t make this multiple URL check !?

Comment: That is a multiple url check. It says, "if url is equal to showbasket.html OR url is equal to order1.html" etc etc

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you got your if condition right:

```
if (url == showbasket.html || url == order1.html || ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is valid, but it will not do what you want

```
if (url==showbasket.html||order1.html
```

"url==showbasket.html" checks if "url" is equal to the "html" attribute of object "showbasket". Since showbasket does not exist, your code will throw an exception.

"||order1.html" means the same, check if the "html" attribute of "order1" object is "true"

Like others have said, what you want to do is :

```
if ( url == "showbasket.html" || url == "order1.html"
```